# MySQL server slows down 24 hours after reboot

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQl server which slows down every 22-24 hours after restarting mysql. After restarting mysql it starts working properly and after about 20 hours it starts to slow down. I increased the tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size to 256M. It hasn't solved the problem.

Here is my.cnf configuration:

```
max_connections = 1000
max_allowed_packet = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size =15G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_read_io_threads = 4
innodb_write_io_threads = 4
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
key_buffer_size = 24M
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
event_scheduler = ON
wait_timeout = 300
interactive_timeout = 30
```

It is a standalone VM with 32 GB RAM. No other major programs are running in that VM.

Comment: What is the memory allocation on your server? How much is the total RAM, how much RAM is allocated to other programs?

Comment: It is a standalone VM with 32 GB RAM. No other major programs are running in that VM.

Comment: Additional DB information request at 20 hours of uptime, please. 
OS, Version? 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Additional DB information request after running SLOW for two hours, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after 2 hours of SLOW  UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server SLOW workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` needs to be only 70% of available RAM.
- The default 151 `max_connections` is likely to be adequate; if you think not, please explain why.
- `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` should be no more than 1% of RAM.  If you think you need them bigger then I think we need to look at the queries and indexes that lead you to that conclusion.  And then discuss "composite" indexes.

Comment: Reduced the "tmp_table_size" and "max_heap_table_size" to 1 M and set the "innodb_buffer_pool_size" to 70% of RAM. Lets see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @Goku__         What is your situation at this time?  Still need assistance?

Comment: @Goku__  Are you still struggling?  Post some data requested (July 27, 2023) so we can assist, please.